# ERROR Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type in c

Tags: c

I Have this error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type main_dict ->size = 0;

What means this error? How I can fix it?

**dictionary.c**

```
struct _Dictionary_t {  
  char **dict;
  int size;
};

Dictionary dict_new (void){

  Dictionary dict_new = NULL;
  dict_new = calloc(1,sizeof(struct _Dictionary_t));
  assert(dict_new != NULL);
  dict_new -> dict = NULL; 
  return (dict_new);
}
```

**dictionary.h**

```
typedef struct _Dictionary_t *Dictionary;

Dictionary dict_new (void);
```

**main.c**

```
int main(void){

  int a;
  main_dict = dict_new();
  a = main_dict->size;
  if(a == 0){
      printf("I'll be here if I fix the error \n")
  }    
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What type is `main_dict`? Where are your `#include` statements? With the error that you are seeing there is clearly code that you've decided to not include in your post.

Answer (score 2):

> What means this error?

The forward declaration

```
typedef struct _Dictionary_t *Dictionary;
```

doesn't give a clue as to what members `struct _Dictionary_t` might have.

You cannot use `main_dict->size` unless the definition of `struct` is visible at that point in the code. Since the definition of the `struct` is in `dictionary.c`, its definition is not visible to anything in `main.c`.

> How I can fix it?

**Solution 1**

Move the definition of the `struct` to the .h file.

**Solution 2**

Provide functions that allow you to get and set the members of the `struct`.

In **dictionary.h**:

```
void setDictionarySize(Dictionary dict, int size);
int getDictionarySize((Dictionary dict);
```

Implement them in **dictioary.c**.

Use the function in **main.c**. Replace

```
a = main_dict->size;
```

by

```
a = getDictionarySize(main_dict);
```